# How to dealloc first page in UIPageViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipageviewcontroller

in iOS 6 it seems that the UIPageViewController is not deallocing the first page that is passed to it via

[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers ...

Whenever I turn a page it is dealloced except this first one in the viewControllers array.

Anyone an idea how I may get rid of this first page?

Comment: I'm wondering if you ever found a solution to this.  It still seems to happen on iOS 7.

Comment: I'm facing same problem :(...nobody knows why?